# Conteo de "n" ingreso por el usuario

Tags: java, java-swing

**Saludos** este código hace que cuente los ingreso, pero solo saca uno, saben el error, pienso que debo hacerlo recursivo y ustedes?

```
JButton btnVentanilla_1 = new JButton("Ventanilla N\u00B01");
    btnVentanilla_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    btnVentanilla_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int cont = 0;
            if (txtTurnos != null) {
                ++cont;
                txtTurnos.setText(String.valueOf(cont));
            }

        }
    });
```

[image: Ingreso]

Comment: No se nada de Java pero has intentado sacando `int cont = 0` fuera de la función `actionPerformed`?

Comment: Por logica cada vez que clickeas el boton creas una nueva variable con valor 0 y a esa variable le añades 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, si me funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que cada vez que se llama al evento

> public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

al apretar el botón, el programa esta re escribiendo la variable "cont"
Eso provoca que cada vez que aprietes el botón la variable queda rebotando entre 1 y 0.
Para arreglarlo solo debes mover la instanciación de la variable hacia afuera, de esta forma:

```
 int cont = 0;
 btnVentanilla_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        if (txtTurnos != null) {
            ++cont;
            txtTurnos.setText(String.valueOf(cont));
        }

    }
});
```

Asi la variable no es reseteada cada vez que apretas el boton y se le suma uno cada vez que lo aprietas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funcionó!

Comment: Tu explicación fue simple pero muy lógica, gracias.